# Paperclip avatar update original while keeping old resized images

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, paperclip

I am using paperclip with s3 in a rails 4 app. It is working fine everywhere, but I have a specific use case that is requiring some special behavior.

I need to upload an image as an avatar, and have it resize to all the thumbnail sizes, but then I need to be able to update *only the original image*, while preserving all the thumbnail links.

Currently, I'm using a Proc to determine attachment sizes based on a class variable. This is causing `image 1` to be uploaded and resized, then I am setting `image 2` with no styles. I was hoping this would create all the thumbs, then replace the original. Unfortunately, it is updating the URLs for each size, but they are empty.

tl;dr - I need to have avatars resized, but I need to be able to update ONLY the original and leave the rest alone.

**Controller**

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController


  # POST /students/:id/avatar
  def new_avatar
    current_student.avatar = params[:avatar]
    current_student.set_orginial_only TRUE
    current_student.avatar = params[:avatar_orig]
    if current_student.save
      render json: current_student, serializer: StudentAvatarSerializer, status: 200
    else
      render json: ErrorSerializer.new(current_student), status: 400
    end
  end

  # DELETE /students/:id/avatar
  def destroy_avatar
    current_student.avatar.destroy
    if current_student.save
      render json: {success: true}, status: 200
    else
      render json: ErrorSerializer.new(current_student), status: 400
    end
  end

  private

  # find student by id and cache
  def current_student
    @student ||= Student.find(params[:id])
  end


end
```

**Model**

```
class Student < ActiveRecord::Base

  @@orginial_only = FALSE

  def set_orginial_only value
    @@orginial_only = value
  end


  # Paperclip attachements
  has_attached_file :avatar, :styles => Proc.new { |clip| clip.instance.attachment_sizes },
                    path: "/:class/:attachment/:id/:content_type_extension/:style/:filename",
                    :default_url => "/images/:style/missing.png"


  validates_attachment_content_type :avatar, :content_type => /image/
  validates_attachment_size :avatar, :in => 0..2.megabytes

  def attachment_sizes
    if @@orginial_only
     styles = {} 
    else 
      styles = {
        tiny: '50x50#',
        tiny_retina: '100x100#',
        small: '60x60#',
        small_retina: '120x120#',
        medium: '108x108#',
        medium_retina: '216x216#',
        large: '205x205#',
        large_retina: '410x410#'
      } 
    end
    styles
  end
end
```

Is there a way to only update the original image while keeping all my thumbs?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: I ended up just using paperclip for the resized image, and aws-sdk to manually replace the original image in the paperclip assigned path.